# How can I make a constraint so that the appointment cannot be repeated?

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I want to make a constraint so that the appointment with a certain doctor cannot be repeated more than once. For example, if a person chooses an appointment on 11/09/2021 from 15:00 until 15:30, the same appointment cannot be booked again at the same doctor.
phpMyAdmin virgin is: Server version: 10.4.10-MariaDB

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE appointments (
    AppId     int(11) PRIMARY,
    docID     int(11),
    patientID int(11),
    AppStart  datetime,
    AppEnd    datetime
  )
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
alter table appointments
add constraint unique_dr_app_start unique (docID, AppStart);
```

Example:

```
insert into appointments (AppId, docID, AppStart) 
values (1, 123, '2021-11-25 12:30:00'); -- OK

insert into appointments (AppId, docID, AppStart) 
values (2, 123, '2021-11-25 10:30:00'); -- OK

insert into appointments (AppId, docID, AppStart)
values (3, 123, '2021-11-25 12:30:00'); -- error
```

> Duplicate entry '123-2021-11-25 12:30:00' for key 'unique_dr_app_start'

**EDIT -- Include end appointment validation**

You can additionally set up the constraint:

```
alter table appointments
add constraint unique_dr_app_end unique (docID, AppEnd);
```

You can see it at work by trying:

```
insert into appointments (AppId, docID, AppStart) 
values (4, 123, '2021-11-25 10:30:00'); -- error
```

> Duplicate entry '123-2021-11-25 10:30:00' for key 'unique_dr_app_start'

Comment: There must be a start time for the appointment and an end time for the appointment, and the time between them must be unique. thank you

Comment: @oliver Added the extra constraint as requested